# how could i print my panel, from the (locationx,locationy) to (panel.getWidth(),panel.getHeight())?

Tags: java, swing, printing, page-size

I have this link, and I can use this sample, to print my panel:
[print example](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/%7Ehall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html)
I use this, to print my panel:

```
PrintUtilities.printComponent(this);
```

"this" is the panel. but after the printing, on the paper the panel is not full. Only the (about) 70% of the Width, and 60% of the Height. (sorry for my english, i am hungarian) The panel size is: 850x1160. This is the example size to an A4 paper: 595x842 -> 70dpi = A4.
Please help me, how to print my panel FULLY to an A4 paper.
Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220115/resizing-jpanel-to-prepare-for-printing-without-removing-it-from-its-original-po

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028497/230513) using `AffineTransformOp `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double factorX = pf.getImageableWidth() / component.getWidth();
double factorY = pf.getImageableHeight() / component.getHeight();
double factor = Math.min( factorX, factorY );
g2.scale(factor,factor);
```

thanks for the answers everybody!